# Missing dll when i move a .exe to another pc (msvcp140.dll, vcruntime140.dll and vcruntime140_1.dll)

Tags: c++, dll, executable, visual-studio-2019

I created two console applications (programmed in C/C++), a client and a server, which exchange messages. The apps work well, but the problem arises when I have to switch the executable to another computer that has no visual studio installed. Once one of the two applications has been launched, I am told that msvcp140.dll, vcruntime140.dll and vcruntime140_1.dll are missing. So I did some research and tried to solve. Some said to configure static linking (Configuration properties -> C / C ++ -> Code generation -> Runtime library: 'Multi-threaded (/MT)'), but once I switched to the second pc I got the message saying that the dlls were missing.

In addition, the executable file has not increased much in size (12KB) compared to before. Some said they tried to use third-party apps or simply switch the dll to the second pc. My goal, however, was to get a single executable that would work autonomously without using installers.

Searching on various forums I have not found solutions; the fact is that the same applications compiled in Dev-Cpp and then brought to the second pc worked perfectly, so there must be a way. The difference I noticed between .exe compiled in Dev and Visual Studio are the size (approximately 1.3 MB and 23KB respectively). So, how can I (if it is possible in VS) get a single .exe (larger or smaller size of the executable is not a problem) that i can move to another computer without the need of any dll?

I'm programming in Visual Studio 2019, student version; as "second pc" I use a virtual machine running Windows 10 (same identical system as the host).
Solution configuration when I build is: Release x86.

Comment: Looks like the other PC has to install the c++ redist package from microsoft.

Comment: @ale03 newline characters are free, you know?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do the single file.
Check Configuration properties -> general -> Use of MFC: select Use standart windows libraies.
And (you wrote about it): (Configuration properties -> C / C ++ -> Code generation -> Runtime library: 'Multi-threaded (/MT)'.

If it isn't help you, You can use 'dependency walker' (freeware software) to check dependencies.

Comment: I checked and it was already selected. 
I don't understand why in Dev it works and in VS it doesn't.